# How to save data from an input form after redirecting with javascript ONLY

Tags: javascript, forms, cookies

I`m trying to keep the information from a form.

```
<form name="welcome_form">
        <p>Prvi igrac: <input type="text" name="prvi"></p>
        <p>Drugi igrac: <input type="text" name="drugi"></p>

    </form>

    <button onclick="submit_form();">Zapocni igru!</button>
```

Submit form validates data from input form, and redirects the user to another page. 
How can i keep the data from the form on the redirected page

Without using jquery,php, just pure javascript.
I tried using cookies, but it didnt work for me.

var prvi_igrac,drugi_igrac;

```
function isValid(unos)
{ 
    return /^\w{3,15}$/.test(unos);
}
function submit_form()
{
    prvi_igrac = document.forms["welcome_form"]["prvi"].value;
    drugi_igrac = document.forms["welcome_form"]["drugi"].value;
    //alert(isValid(prvi_igrac));
    if(isValid(prvi_igrac) == false || isValid(drugi_igrac) == false)
    {
        alert("Ime mora sadrzati 3-15 karaktera i samo slova,brojeve i donju crtu!");
        return;
    }
    document.cookie = "prvi_igrac="+prvi_igrac;
    var x = document.cookie;
    alert(x);


}
```

Tnx in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use localstorage to store your form data on first page using following code.

```
localStorage.setItem('key', 'your data')
```

and then on redirected page yoou can get with below code

```
localStorage.getItem('key')
```